# remove a node from a double linked list in mips

Tags: linked-list, mips, doubly-linked-list

I have been asked for a job for university in which I have to work with lists of objects in categorized form using circular double linked lists. In one of the exercises it asks me to delete a selected category. If the list of objects of the selected category is empty then it should delete only the category and automatically select the next one as the category if it exists, otherwise it should nullify the necessary pointers. If, on the other hand, it is not empty, you must first proceed to delete all the objects, returning the corresponding memory and then proceed to delete the category with the same caveats that were indicated.
The problem is that when I want to add a new category it gives me a memory alignment error and I don't know how to fix it. I would appreciate if someone can help me

```
        .data
slist:      .word 0
cclist:     .word 0
wclist:     .word 0
schedv:     .space 32
menu:       .ascii "\nColecciones de objetos categorizados\n"
        .ascii "====================================\n"
        .ascii "1-Nueva categoria\n"
        .ascii "2-Siguiente categoria\n"
        .ascii "3-Categoria anterior\n"
        .ascii "4-Listar categorias\n"
        .ascii "5-Borrar categoria actual\n"
        .ascii "6-Anexar objeto a la categoria actual\n"
        .ascii "7-Listar objetos de la categoria\n"
        .ascii "8-Borrar objeto de la categoria\n"
        .ascii "0-Salir\n"
        .asciiz "Ingrese la opcion deseada: "
error:      .asciiz "\nError: "
return:     .asciiz "\n"
flecha:     .asciiz "> "
catName:    .asciiz "\nIngrese el nombre de una categoria: "
selCat:     .asciiz "\nSe ha seleccionado la categoria: "
idObj:      .asciiz "\nIngrese el ID del objeto a eliminar: "
objName:    .asciiz "\nIngrese el nombre de un objeto: "
success:    .asciiz "\nLa operación se realizo con exito\n"

        .text
main:       la $t0, schedv # initialization scheduler vector
        la $t1, newcategory
        sw $t1, 0($t0)
        la $t1, nextcategory
        sw $t1, 4($t0)
        la $t1, prevcategory
        sw $t1, 8($t0)
        la $t1, listcategories
        sw $t1, 12($t0)
        la $t1, delcategory
        sw $t1, 16($t0)
        la $t1, newobject
        sw $t1, 20($t0)
        la $t1, listobjects
        sw $t1, 24($t0)
#       la $t1, delobject
#       sw $t1, 28($t0)

mainloop:   li $v0, 4
        la $a0, menu
        syscall
        li $v0, 5
        syscall     # Pedir un entero
        move $t2, $v0
condiciones:    blt $t2, 0, error101
        bgt $t2, 8, error101
        beq $t2, 0, end
        beq $t2, 1, opc1        
        beq $t2, 2, opc2
        beq $t2, 3, opc3    
        beq $t2, 4, opc4
        beq $t2, 5, opc5
        beq $t2, 6, opc6
        beq $t2, 7, opc7
        beq $t2, 8, opc8
        j mainloop
        
opc1:       jal newcategory
        j mainloop
opc2:       jal nextcategory
        j mainloop
opc3:       jal prevcategory
        j mainloop
opc4:       jal listcategories
        j mainloop
opc5:       jal delcategory
        j mainloop
opc6:       jal newobject
        j mainloop
opc7:       jal listobjects
        j mainloop
opc8:       #jal delobjet
        #j mainloop
            
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------#
#               ERRORES                 # 
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------#
        
printerror:     
        move $t0, $a0
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, error
        syscall
        li $v0, 1
        la $a0, ($t0)
        syscall
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, return
        syscall
        j mainloop
error101:   li $a0, 101
        jal printerror
error201:   li $a0, 201
        jal printerror
error202:   li $a0, 202
        jal printerror
error301:   li $a0, 301
        jal printerror
error401:   li $a0, 401
        jal printerror
error501:   li $a0, 501
        jal printerror
error601:   li $a0, 601
        jal printerror  
error602:   li $a0, 602
        jal printerror
error701:   li $a0, 701
        jal printerror      
        
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------#
#               CATEGORIAS              #
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------#

newcategory:    
        addiu $sp, $sp, -4
        sw $ra, 4($sp)
        la $a0, catName # input category name
        jal getblock 
        move $a2, $v0 # $a2 = *char to category name
        la $a0, cclist # $a0 = list
        li $a1, 0 # $a1 = NULL
        jal addnode
        lw $t0, wclist
        bnez $t0, newcategory_end
        sw $v0, wclist # update working list if was NULL        
newcategory_end:
        li $v0, 0 # return success
        lw $ra, 4($sp)
        addiu $sp, $sp, 4
        jr $ra  

nextcategory:   lw $t0, wclist
        beqz $t0, error201 # wclist == 0
        lw $t1, 12($t0)
        beq $t0, $t1, error202 # prevcategory == 0
        sw $t1, wclist # update wclist
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, selCat
        syscall
        lw $t1, 8($t0)
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, ($t0)
        syscall
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, success
        syscall
        li $v0, 0
        jr $ra
        
prevcategory:   lw $t0, wclist
        beqz $t0, error201 
        lw $t0, ($t0)   # $t0 = prevcategory
        beqz $t0, error202 # prevcategory != 0
        sw $t0, wclist # update wclist
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, selCat
        syscall
        lw $t0, 8($t0)
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, ($t0)
        syscall
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, success
        syscall
        li $v0, 0
        jr $ra
        
listcategories: lw $t0, cclist
        beqz $t0, error301 
        lw $t1, wclist # $t1 = selected category in progress
        li $t2, 0 # i = 0 
        lw $t4, cclist #(aux)
catLoop:    bne $t0, $t4, elseCat # cclist != cclist(aux)?
        addi $t2, $t2, 1 # if cclist is repeated: i++
elseCat:    beq $t2, 2, listcategories_end 
        bne $t1, $t0 noeq # skip if wclist != cclist
        li $v0, 4     # (for current category)
        la $a0, flecha
        syscall # ">" 
noeq:       lw $t3, 8($t0)  # category name
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, ($t3)
        syscall # print the category
        lw $t0, 12($t0) # next category
        j catLoop
listcategories_end:
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, success
        syscall
        li $v0, 0
        jr $ra

delcategory:    
        lw $t0, cclist
        beqz $t0, error401
        addiu $sp, $sp, -4
        sw $ra, 4($sp)
        lw $a0, wclist 
        la $a1, slist 
        jal delnode
delcategory_end:
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, success
        syscall
        li $v0, 0
        lw $ra, 4($sp)
        addiu $sp, $sp, 4
        jr $ra
        
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------#
#               OBJETOS                 #
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------#
        
newobject:  
        lw $t0, cclist 
        beqz $t0, error501
        addiu $sp, $sp, -4
        sw $ra, 4($sp)
        la $a0, objName
        jal getblock
        move $a2, $v0
        lw $t0, wclist
        la $a0, 4($t0)
        li $a1, 0 
        jal addnode
        lw $t0, 0($v0)
        lw $t1, 4($t0)
        addi $t1, $t1, 1
        sw $t1, 4($v0)
newobject_end:  
        li $v0, 0 # return success
        lw $ra, 4($sp)
        addiu $sp, $sp, 4
        jr $ra  
listobjects:    
        lw $t0, wclist # $t0 = selected category in progress
        beqz $t0, error601 # If there are no lists, error code 601
        lw $t0, 4($t0) # $t0 = list of objects of the current category 
        li $t2, 0 # i = 0
        lw $t4, ($t0) # $t4 = first element of object list
objLoop:    bne $t0, $t4, objElse
        addi $t2, $t2, 1 # if cclist is repeated: i++
objElse:    beq $t2, 2, listobjects_end
        lw $t3, 8($t0)  # object name
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, ($t3)
        syscall # print the object
        lw $t4, ($t0) # $t4 = first element of object list
        lw $t0, 12($t0) # next object
        j objLoop
listobjects_end:
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, success
        syscall
        li $v0, 0
        jr $ra
        
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------#
#               NODOS                   #
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------#

        # a0: list address
        # a1: NULL if category, node address if object
        # v0: node address added
addnode:
        addi $sp, $sp, -8
        sw $ra, 8($sp)
        sw $a0, 4($sp)
        jal smalloc
        sw $a1, 4($v0) # set node content
        sw $a2, 8($v0)
        lw $a0, 4($sp)
        lw $t0, ($a0) # first node address
        beqz $t0, addnode_empty_list
addnode_to_end:
        lw $t1, ($t0) # last node address
        # update prev and next pointers of new node
        sw $t1, 0($v0)
        sw $t0, 12($v0)
        # update prev and first node to new node
        sw $v0, 12($t1)
        sw $v0, 0($t0)
        j addnode_exit
addnode_empty_list:
        sw $v0, ($a0)
        sw $v0, 0($v0)
        sw $v0, 12($v0)
addnode_exit:
        lw $ra, 8($sp)
        addi $sp, $sp, 8
        jr $ra
        
        # a0: node address to delete
        # a1: list address where node is deleted
delnode:
        addi $sp, $sp, -8
        sw $ra, 8($sp)
        sw $a0, 4($sp)
        lw $a0, 8($a0) # get block address
        jal sfree # free block
        lw $a0, 4($sp) # restore argument a0
        lw $t0, 12($a0) # get address to next node of a0 node
        beq $a0, $t0, delnode_point_self
        lw $t1, 0($a0) # get address to prev node
        sw $t1, 0($t0)
        sw $t0, 12($t1)
        lw $t1, 0($a1) # get address to first node again
        bne $a0, $t1, delnode_exit
        sw $t0, ($a1) # list point to next node
        j delnode_exit
delnode_point_self:
        sw $zero, ($a1) # only one node
delnode_exit:
        jal sfree
        lw $ra, 8($sp)
        addi $sp, $sp, 8
        jr $ra

            
        # a0: msg to ask
        # v0: block address allocated with string

getblock:   addi $sp, $sp, -4
        sw $ra, 4($sp)
        li $v0, 4
        syscall
        jal smalloc
        move $a0, $v0
        li $a1, 16
        li $v0, 8
        syscall
        move $v0, $a0
        lw $ra, 4($sp)
        addi $sp, $sp, 4
        jr $ra

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------#
#           GESTION DE MEMORIA              # 
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------#

smalloc:
        lw $t0, slist   
        beqz $t0, sbrk
        move $v0, $t0
        lw $t0, 12($t0)
        sw $t0, slist
        jr $ra  # return
sbrk:
        li $a0, 16 # node size fixed 4 words
        li $v0, 9
        syscall 
        jr $ra  # return
sfree:
        lw $t0, slist
        sw $t0, 12($a0)
        sw $a0, slist # $a0 node address in unused list
        jr $ra  # return
end:
```

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger?  Generally speaking, with a memory error, you suspect the register being used as the base register for that memory operation instruction.  Check that register's value and if it is bad at the time of the error, then find out how it got that bad address by looking earlier in the flow of the program.  You can't really expect us to debug your project, but if you give specific details we may be able to give you some insights.  In any case you may need to step up your debugging skills.

Comment: Usually a memory alignment error happens when you try to use `lw` or `sw` to load/store at a destination address that isn't a multiple of 4. If you have a debugger, it should tell you which instruction causes the error. Then you'll need to see what's in the register that's in parentheses.

Comment: Also rather than having a long sequence of `beq`s you're probably better off having an array of function pointers and using `jalr` to select the desired function